# Which is the most accurate notation for function recomposition?

Tags: functions, notation, definition

Having the definition of *recomposition of functions* as the composition of a function with itself (ex: $f\circ f\circ x$), which is the most accurate way to denote this type of operation?

Examples:

- The power notation: $\underbrace{f\circ f\cdots\circ f}_n = f^n, \underbrace{f\circ f\cdots\circ f}_n\circ x = f^n(x)$
- The power composition notation: $\underbrace{f\circ f\cdots\circ f}_n = f^{\circ n}, \underbrace{f\circ f\cdots\circ f}_n\circ x = f^{\circ n}(x)$
- The ***re**composition* notation: $\underbrace{f\circ f\cdots\circ f}_n = f\overset n\circ, \underbrace{f\circ f\cdots\circ f}_n\circ x = f\overset n\circ(x)$

Note: for this question, I'm not in need of very strict answering in regard of things like domain, image / co-domain definition.

Comment: When it helps clarify, I write this as $f^{\circ n}$

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to speak of 'an accurate notation' in this way. Just pick a notation you think is clear, and if there's a possibility of ambiguity, just spell out what you are doing to your readers. Then, everyone will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

As there's thousands of ways things can be done in math, its very unusual to have a *most accurate way* of doing something.

For example, when dealing with algebraic transformations, like matrix multiplication, $f^n(x)$ can be very handy, as it is easy to write, and don't change the operation at all (it's all some sort of multiplication).

But when dealing with, for example, trigonometric functions, the *easiness* becomes ambiguity: is $\sin^2 x = (\sin x)^2$ or $\sin(\sin x)$? Is $\sin^{- 1} x = {1\over \sin x} = \csc x$ or $\arcsin x$?

So, when dealing with this type of functions (or, in general, whenever **not** dealing *only with* the first type of functions), the ***re**composition* notation comes into hand:

Letting $f$ be $f\circ x$, here are some notable identities:

- $f\circ f\circ x = f\overset 2\circ x$
- "$x\circ f$" $ = f\overset {- 1}\circ x$
- $f\overset {n + 1}\circ x = f\circ f\overset n\circ x = f\overset n\circ f\circ x = x$
- $f\overset {n + m}\circ x = f\overset m\circ f\overset n\circ x = f\overset n\circ f\overset m\circ x = x$
- $f\overset {- 1}\circ (f\circ x) = f\circ (f\overset {- 1}\circ x) = x$
- $f\overset {- n}\circ (f\overset n\circ x) = f\overset n\circ (f\overset {- n}\circ x) = x$
- [Involutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)) obey $f\overset 2\circ x = x$ (like ${1\over x}$, $- x$, and $\bar z$)
- $\operatorname{arc [something]}(x)$ can be expressed / defined as $\operatorname{[something]}\overset{- 1}\circ x$ (ex: $\arcsin x := \sin\overset{- 1}\circ x)$
- $g = f\overset n\circ\iff f \overset 1 = g\overset{1\over n}\circ\Rightarrow g\overset m\circ = f\overset n\circ\iff f \overset 1 = g\overset{m\div n}\circ$

One use for the recomposition of functions, besides of dealing with iterations of functions, is expressing the growth of a function based in other functions².

One thing that could be called an abuse of notation is: $f\overset{2}{\overline{\circ\circ}} x=f\overset{f\circ x}\circ x$.

Notes:

1. There certainly are cases where there are multiple solutions to these equations.
2. No article for reference.

Comment: I have never seen $f \circ x$ as a notation for $f(x)$. I can see how you can make it work if you identify $x$ with the constant function $(\cdot) \mapsto x$, but that seems very obscure. Likewise, I have never seen $x \circ f$ fo $f^{-1}(x)$. Finally, I have never heard the word "recomposition" used in this context.